# Extracting relations with osmnx?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx, relation

I am using osmnx package https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html
to extract data from OSM. I aim to obtain relations from the cyclist node network in Flanders. After some info about tagging, I found the most useful tag could be "network:type"; but when I used it I only obtain nodes as element type.

Maybe my approach to extract relations is inadequate?.

Please any advice will be useful :)

```
place= "Leuven, Flanders, Belgium"
tags = {"network:type":"node_network"}
Leuven_test = ox.geometries_from_place(place,tags2,which_result=None)
```

The results only extract nodes as element types.

```
Leuven_test.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

[Right at the beginning of the osmnx.geometries module definition](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.geometries)

"You can use this module to query for nodes, ways, and relations (the latter of type “multipolygon” or “boundary” only)"

That relation isn't “multipolygon” or “boundary”.